# Fortran F90 equivalent of void* with MPI or another way to do runtime type checking?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, void-pointers

I've spent days on this already and searched a LOT of stuff (including this site and Fortran documentation) so please excuse me if this is actually a really simple question, but I'm relatively inexperienced in Fortran and come from a C++/C#/Java background.
I am using the F90 MPI compiler so am unable to make use of any more recent features, and I've no options on this.

I am trying to wrap the MPI functions to make a communications layer and the direct MPI interaction encapsulated (just can't shake those OO habits!). To that end I need to pass data to/from my wrapper functions.

The [MPI spec](http://www.open-mpi.org/~jsquyres/www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Send.3.php) has this prototype for example:

```
INCLUDE ’mpif.h’
MPI_SEND(BUF, COUNT, DATATYPE, DEST, TAG, COMM, IERROR)
    <type>    BUF(*)
    INTEGER    COUNT, DATATYPE, DEST, TAG, COMM, IERROR
```

And my subroutine is this:

```
SUBROUTINE empi_wrap_open_send(sendbuf, size, targetid, the_type)
```

where I have had to add 'the_type' to let me pass the correct MPI dataype through {*}. However, I cannot get the subroutine's subsequent internal declaration of 'sendbuf' to compile. I have tried:

```
TYPE(C_PTR) :: sendbuf   !with 'USE iso_c_binding'
TYPE :: sendbuf(*)
POINTER :: sendbuf
POINTER, TYPE(*) :: sendbuf
```

My last resort is to remove my 'IMPLICIT NONE' but I fear that way may lead to disaster!
Any tips on how to do this properly, I'd be most grateful. It can't be that hard surely?

{*} I'd rather do runtime type checking, viz.:

```
SELECT TYPE (sendbuf)
TYPE is (INTEGER)
    empi_type = MPI_INTEGER
TYPE is (DOUBLE)
    empi_type = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
END SELECT
```

but I can live with the hack.

Comment: You mention Fortran 90 a fair bit, but you're using (at least) Fortran 2003.  Could you clarify which compiler (`mpif90` would wrap around something, if that is what you mean) as some have support which will make things much easier?

Comment: Removing `implicit none` will not make this work: that allows implicit typing whereas you want somethng very different.

Comment: Yes, there's no way I want to remove 'implicit none'. I'm not knowingly using F2003, I'm using mpif90. I'm trying to wrap the MPI routines, that's all, no complier complications!

Comment: `select type` didn't work, hence my hack! and I think that the `iso_c_binding` also failed hence my problem with the `TYPE(C_PTR)` option too. Am I basically trying to do the impossible?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, then generics may be a way to go.  I've no time to say more now, I'm afraid.

Comment: No probs, thanks for the hint, I'll investigate.

Comment: The fact that you use something called `mpif90` does not mean the compiler is only Fortran 90. It is just a name to a wrapper to the actual compiler, you must look into it's manual to see what it actually is. Fortran 90 is essentially dead, everyone uses at least Fortran 95, even though he may be calling it "Fortran 90". You ARE actually using Fortran 2003. `TYPE(C_PTR)`  and `SELECT TYPE` are pure Fortran 2003.

Comment: Also note in Fortran 90 and later you should forget `include 'mpif.h'` (Why the hell does OpenMPI still keep it as the default in their manual??? Soon even the time of `use mpi_f08` wil come!) and use `use mpi`. You will get a lot of error checking for free.

Comment: @VladimirF both 'type(c_ptr)' and 'select type' failed to compile as I already mentioned, hence my conclusion that it's not f2003 sadly. But I'll try the alternative for including mpi. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't include the error message we have no way finding out the reason why it does not compile except reading your mind over the internet.

Answer (score 3):

I would use generics. Sure, it brings some code duplication, but you get the type checking and other good features. The following is a snippet of my actual code used in production. I did not find it useful to wrap Send and Recv in this way (I use different internal procedures as wrappers), but I do wrap the MPI colectives. The last function shows that you do not have to pass the size at all.

```
  interface mpi_co_min
    module procedure mpi_co_min_32
    module procedure mpi_co_min_64
  end interface

  ...

  interface mpi_co_reduce
    module procedure mpi_co_reduce_32
    module procedure mpi_co_reduce_64
    module procedure mpi_co_reduce_32_1d
    ...
  end interface

  ...

  function mpi_co_min_32(x) result(res)
    real(real32) :: res
    real(real32),intent(in) :: x
    integer ie

    res = mpi_co_reduce(x, MPI_MIN, global_comm)
  end function

  function mpi_co_min_64(x) result(res)
    real(real64) :: res
    real(real64),intent(in) :: x
    integer ie

    res = mpi_co_reduce(x, MPI_MIN, global_comm)
  end function

  function mpi_co_reduce_32(x,op,comm) result(res)
    real(real32) :: res
    real(real32),intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: op, comm
    integer ie

    call MPI_AllReduce(x, res, &
                       count=1, datatype=MPI_MI_REAL32, op=op, &
                       comm=comm, ierror=ie)
  end function

  function mpi_co_reduce_64(x,op,comm) result(res)
    real(real64) :: res
    real(real64),intent(in) :: x
    integer, intent(in) :: op, comm
    integer ie

    call MPI_AllReduce(x, res, &
                       count=1, datatype=MY_MPI_REAL64, op=op, &
                       comm=comm, ierror=ie)
  end function

  function mpi_co_reduce_32_1d(x,op,comm) result(res)
    real(real32),intent(in) :: x(:)
    real(real32) :: res(size(x))
    integer, intent(in) :: op, comm
    integer ie

    call MPI_AllReduce(x, res, &
                       count=size(x), datatype=MY_MPI_REAL32, op=op, &
                       comm=comm, ierror=ie)
  end function
```